# When to use Eigen::Vector vs std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

Because of external dependencies, I'm required to write some data in a `Eigen::VectorXi` container.

However, there are other times in which I'm not required to use en `Eigen::VectorXi` as a container, and I may use a standard `std::vector<int>`

Currently I have `Eigen` and `std` vectors sprinkled through my code. The only times in which I decide to use an `std:vector` is when I'll be making insertions on the fly, since resizing and reinserting is more tedious (and possibly computationally expensive) than using `push_back(<value>)`

I'd like to be sure that I'm using one or the other in the right time, instead of randomly choosing. What are the right instances to use `Eigen::Vector` instead of `std::vector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes in Eigen represent mathematical objects. In this case, a mathematical vector, with all the typical operations on vectors, like multiplication with a matrix or scalar product.

`std::vector` is essentially an (dynamic) array, storing a list of data in consecutive space. Typical operations would be appending data or sorting it.

When you decide what you want to use, simply ask yourself if this is a mathematical vector. You could extend both to hold what the other is supposed to, creating a scalar product over std::vector, but why would you? Eigen does that already. Using it for what it is intended makes it clear to everybody what you represent, increasing readability.

Comment: The library that I'm using (libigl) doesn't follow that premise. I think is meant to make it more cache friendly and memory efficient. Are there any fundamental differences in memory, speed of access between Eigen and std vector? (I agree that readability is a big plus)

Comment: @Javier It's safe to assume that the methods which both provide are written efficiently, which means that each one is strong on all methods it provides. If we talk about access, that should be efficient in both cases. If you work with sparse data, Eigen is more efficient in memory, since it has a sparse vector class. std::vector will store data dense, being consecutive.

Comment: Eigen implements vectorized operations on its data structures. So if your data is going to go through math operations, Eigen is probably what you want.